# how to create a JSON object from a TSV file containing key/value pairs with jq

Tags: json, object, jq, csvtojson

I a have a short TSV stream that outputs key/value pairs and I would like to create a JSON object out of it, with `jq`.

For now I have this code, which generates a stack of JSON objects:

```bash
printf '%s\t%s\n' key1 val1 key2 val2 |

jq -R 'rtrimstr("\n") | split("\t") | { (.[0]): .[1] }'
```

```json
{
  "key1": "val1"
}
{
  "key2": "val2"
}
```

I can pipe it to `jq -s 'add'` for getting my expected output:

```json
{
  "key1": "val1",
  "key2": "val2"
}
```

But, is it possible to get this output with a **single** `jq` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-n` and `inputs` to access the stream item by item.

For instance using `reduce`:

```bash
jq -Rn 'reduce (inputs/"\t") as [$k,$v] ({}; .[$k] = $v)'
```

Or using `from_entries`:

```bash
jq -Rn '[inputs/"\t" | {key: .[0], value: .[1]}] | from_entries'
```

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the `-n` in my tests with `inputs` and `reduce`

Comment: @Fravadona Sometimes the `-n` is not indispensable. In such cases you can use `.` in the initial context of `reduce`, and process just the subsequent items using `input(s)`. Example: `printf '%s\n' val1 val2 val3 | jq -R 'reduce inputs as $i (.; . += ",\($i)")'` yields `"val1,val2,val3"`.